Variable legend outlined in appropriate color, but filled with black dot
I have used ggplot in R to generate a dot plot with three "samples" (Adipocytes, BAT and WAT) which are colored by ""group". The plot is correct, but the "group" legend is not. It should be completely filled with the assigned group color, but it is only outlined in the color and filled with a black dot. How do I specify I would like the legend filled as well?
Here is my current plot. You can see what I'm talking about.

Here is my code:
#IQR stats
iqr = function(All, lower = 0.25, upper = 0.75) {
  data.frame(
    y = median(All),
    ymin = quantile(All, lower),
    ymax = quantile(All, upper)
  )
}
#Import Data
df <- read.csv("All_processes_0.1_radians_invitro_BAT_WAT.csv")

#Plot data
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(process), y = CTrad, color=group)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(200,475,25)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=sample, size=-log(kuiper_q))) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", position="dodge", stackdir="centerwhole", binwidth=.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = iqr, geom = "pointrange", colour = "black")

Here is my data.frame
> dput(df)
structure(list(sample = c("Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", 
"Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", 
"Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", 
"Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "Adipocytes", 
"Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", "Adipocytes", 
"Adipocytes", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT"), process = c("Cell_cycle_Adipocytes", "Cell_cycle_Adipocytes", 
"Cell_cycle_Adipocytes", "Cell_cycle_Adipocytes", "Cell_cycle_Adipocytes", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", 
"Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_BAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", 
"Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", 
"Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", 
"Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", 
"Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "Cell_cycle_WAT", "ECM_Adipocytes", 
"ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", 
"ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", 
"ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_Adipocytes", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", 
"ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", 
"ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", "ECM_BAT", 
"ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", 
"ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", 
"ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", 
"ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "ECM_WAT", "GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", 
"GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", "GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", "GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", 
"GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", "GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", "GTPase_cycling_Adipocytes", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_BAT", "GTPase_cycling_WAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_WAT", "GTPase_cycling_WAT", "GTPase_cycling_WAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_WAT", "GTPase_cycling_WAT", "GTPase_cycling_WAT", 
"GTPase_cycling_WAT"), group = c("Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", "Cell_cycle", 
"ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", 
"ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", 
"ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", 
"ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", 
"ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", "ECM", 
"ECM", "ECM", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", 
"GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling", "GTPase_cycling"
), pathway = c("REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT", "REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION", 
"REACTOME_AMPLIFICATION_OF_SIGNAL_FROM_THE_KINETOCHORES", "REACTOME_CELLULAR_SENESCENCE", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
"HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE_CHECKPOINTS", 
"REACTOME_M_PHASE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", "KEGG_CELL_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE", "REACTOME_CYCLIN_A_CDK2_ASSOCIATED_EVENTS_AT_S_PHASE_ENTRY", 
"REACTOME_S_PHASE", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_G2_G2_M_PHASES", "REACTOME_G2_M_CHECKPOINTS", 
"REACTOME_G2_M_DNA_DAMAGE_CHECKPOINT", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_G1_PHASE_AND_G1_S_TRANSITION", 
"REACTOME_G1_S_TRANSITION", "REACTOME_DNA_REPLICATION_PRE_INITIATION", 
"REACTOME_G1_S_DNA_DAMAGE_CHECKPOINTS", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT", 
"REACTOME_CYCLIN_D_ASSOCIATED_EVENTS_IN_G1", "REACTOME_RECOGNITION_OF_DNA_DAMAGE_BY_PCNA_CONTAINING_REPLICATION_COMPLEX", 
"REACTOME_ASSEMBLY_OF_THE_PRE_REPLICATIVE_COMPLEX", "REACTOME_APC_C_CDH1_MEDIATED_DEGRADATION_OF_CDC20_AND_OTHER_APC_C_CDH1_TARGETED_PROTEINS_IN_LATE_MITOSIS_EARLY_G1", 
"HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1", "HALLMARK_E2F_TARGETS", "REACTOME_TP53_REGULATES_TRANSCRIPTION_OF_DNA_REPAIR_GENES", 
"REACTOME_DNA_REPAIR", "REACTOME_DNA_REPLICATION", "REACTOME_RECRUITMENT_OF_NUMA_TO_MITOTIC_CENTROSOMES", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROPHASE", "REACTOME_APC_C_MEDIATED_DEGRADATION_OF_CELL_CYCLE_PROTEINS", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_METAPHASE_AND_ANAPHASE", "REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION", 
"HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT", "HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1", "REACTOME_AMPLIFICATION_OF_SIGNAL_FROM_THE_KINETOCHORES", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT", "REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_METAPHASE_AND_ANAPHASE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_M_PHASE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE_CHECKPOINTS", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_G2_G2_M_PHASES", 
"KEGG_CELL_CYCLE", "REACTOME_SEPARATION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATIDS", 
"REACTOME_POSTMITOTIC_NUCLEAR_PORE_COMPLEX_NPC_REFORMATION", 
"REACTOME_NUCLEAR_ENVELOPE_NE_REASSEMBLY", "HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS", 
"REACTOME_ELASTIC_FIBRE_FORMATION", "HALLMARK_EPITHELIAL_MESENCHYMAL_TRANSITION", 
"KEGG_ECM_RECEPTOR_INTERACTION", "KEGG_FOCAL_ADHESION", "REACTOME_MOLECULES_ASSOCIATED_WITH_ELASTIC_FIBRES", 
"REACTOME_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX_ORGANIZATION", "REACTOME_DEGRADATION_OF_THE_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX", 
"REACTOME_ACTIVATION_OF_MATRIX_METALLOPROTEINASES", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_DEGRADATION", 
"HALLMARK_MYOGENESIS", "HALLMARK_EPITHELIAL_MESENCHYMAL_TRANSITION", 
"REACTOME_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX_ORGANIZATION", "KEGG_FOCAL_ADHESION", 
"KEGG_ECM_RECEPTOR_INTERACTION", "REACTOME_DEGRADATION_OF_THE_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX", 
"REACTOME_COLLAGEN_FORMATION", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_DEGRADATION", 
"KEGG_CELL_ADHESION_MOLECULES_CAMS", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_BIOSYNTHESIS_AND_MODIFYING_ENZYMES", 
"REACTOME_ECM_PROTEOGLYCANS", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_CHAIN_TRIMERIZATION", 
"REACTOME_INTEGRIN_CELL_SURFACE_INTERACTIONS", "REACTOME_CELL_CELL_COMMUNICATION", 
"REACTOME_NCAM1_INTERACTIONS", "REACTOME_ANCHORING_OF_THE_BASAL_BODY_TO_THE_PLASMA_MEMBRANE", 
"REACTOME_COLLAGEN_DEGRADATION", "REACTOME_INTEGRIN_CELL_SURFACE_INTERACTIONS", 
"REACTOME_ASSEMBLY_OF_COLLAGEN_FIBRILS_AND_OTHER_MULTIMERIC_STRUCTURES", 
"REACTOME_COLLAGEN_FORMATION", "REACTOME_DEGRADATION_OF_THE_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX", 
"REACTOME_EXTRACELLULAR_MATRIX_ORGANIZATION", "HALLMARK_EPITHELIAL_MESENCHYMAL_TRANSITION", 
"KEGG_ECM_RECEPTOR_INTERACTION", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_BIOSYNTHESIS_AND_MODIFYING_ENZYMES", 
"REACTOME_NCAM1_INTERACTIONS", "REACTOME_NCAM_SIGNALING_FOR_NEURITE_OUT_GROWTH", 
"REACTOME_ECM_PROTEOGLYCANS", "REACTOME_CELL_SURFACE_INTERACTIONS_AT_THE_VASCULAR_WALL", 
"REACTOME_NON_INTEGRIN_MEMBRANE_ECM_INTERACTIONS", "REACTOME_CELL_CELL_COMMUNICATION", 
"KEGG_FOCAL_ADHESION", "REACTOME_COLLAGEN_CHAIN_TRIMERIZATION", 
"REACTOME_ELASTIC_FIBRE_FORMATION", "REACTOME_CELL_JUNCTION_ORGANIZATION", 
"REACTOME_COLLAGEN_BIOSYNTHESIS_AND_MODIFYING_ENZYMES", "REACTOME_CROSSLINKING_OF_COLLAGEN_FIBRILS", 
"REACTOME_SIGNALING_BY_RHO_GTPASES_MIRO_GTPASES_AND_RHOBTB3", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_EFFECTORS", "REACTOME_RHO_GTPASES_ACTIVATE_FORMINS", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_SIGNALING_BY_GPCR", "REACTOME_RAC1_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_GPCR_LIGAND_BINDING", "REACTOME_CDC42_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_INTRACELLULAR_SIGNALING_BY_SECOND_MESSENGERS", "REACTOME_RAC1_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_RAC2_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RAC3_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RAS_PROCESSING", 
"REACTOME_REGULATION_OF_RAS_BY_GAPS", "REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_EFFECTORS", "REACTOME_RHO_GTPASES_ACTIVATE_FORMINS", 
"REACTOME_RHOA_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RHOB_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RHOC_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_RHOD_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RHOG_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RHOQ_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_RHOU_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_RND2_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_SIGNALING_BY_RHO_GTPASES_MIRO_GTPASES_AND_RHOBTB3", 
"HALLMARK_KRAS_SIGNALING_UP", "REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_EFFECTORS", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASE_CYCLE", "REACTOME_SIGNALING_BY_RHO_GTPASES_MIRO_GTPASES_AND_RHOBTB3", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASES_ACTIVATE_FORMINS", "REACTOME_GENERATION_OF_SECOND_MESSENGER_MOLECULES", 
"REACTOME_RHO_GTPASES_ACTIVATE_WASPS_AND_WAVES", "REACTOME_RHOA_GTPASE_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_RAF_ACTIVATION"), total_ccgs = c(21L, 20L, 18L, 27L, 
31L, 59L, 59L, 71L, 101L, 149L, 40L, 49L, 27L, 48L, 54L, 41L, 
19L, 41L, 36L, 31L, 21L, 27L, 17L, 10L, 27L, 25L, 55L, 52L, 16L, 
65L, 37L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 62L, 26L, 50L, 55L, 21L, 24L, 28L, 42L, 
45L, 51L, 123L, 74L, 59L, 48L, 33L, 41L, 9L, 19L, 75L, 15L, 71L, 
31L, 61L, 13L, 69L, 31L, 7L, 18L, 49L, 70L, 65L, 68L, 26L, 27L, 
25L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 14L, 12L, 22L, 20L, 7L, 29L, 18L, 21L, 21L, 
25L, 27L, 52L, 54L, 25L, 19L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 52L, 
12L, 9L, 13L, 19L, 10L, 159L, 54L, 27L, 114L, 106L, 56L, 46L, 
28L, 79L, 49L, 25L, 26L, 9L, 20L, 134L, 60L, 30L, 48L, 24L, 25L, 
18L, 22L, 17L, 12L, 15L, 181L, 61L, 46L, 107L, 147L, 30L, 5L, 
7L, 37L, 8L), kuiper_q = c(2e-04, 8e-04, 0.0012, 0.0125, 0.0122, 
1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.007542857, 0.0161, 0.01932, 
0.01932, 0.01932, 0.025044444, 0.03442069, 0.03442069, 0.036672222, 
0.0406, 0.048555556, 0.0546, 0.062635616, 0.066876923, 0.067253165, 
0.083925532, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.027906667, 0.03521875, 
0.042714286, 0.066518421, 0.010733333, 0.054455882, 1e-04, 1e-04, 
1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.0068, 0.00927, 0.0139, 0.04749, 
0.0695, 0.08737, 0.09611, 0.01853, 0.00927, 0.0278, 1e-04, 1e-04, 
0.00467, 0.00733, 0.011, 0.02391, 0.0372, 0.04565, 0.06331, 0.07337, 
0.03294, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.0044, 0.01056, 0.0161, 0.02415, 0.025044444, 
0.0264, 0.0276, 0.0322, 0.03442069, 0.039630769, 0.086872917, 
0.048036066, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 
0.0032, 0.0058, 0.01668, 0.01986, 0.02527, 0.03574, 0.03707, 
0.04236, 0.04236, 0.07089, 0.07892, 0.08737, 0.04296, 0.01668, 
0.04236, 1e-04, 0.05231, 0.05735, 0.05735, 0.06331, 0.09838, 
0.09591, 0.051715152, 0.021466667, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.088872, 
0.073083146, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.03442069, 1e-04, 0.0680225, 0.0406, 
0.072262791, 0.021466667, 0.010733333, 0.087305155, 0.059864789, 
1e-04, 0.046333333, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.00927, 0.04236, 0.07599, 
0.08803, 0.05338), magnitude = c(0.618601878, 0.520553268, 0.582559826, 
0.334789974, 0.367966232, 0.499353427, 0.464848332, 0.399983767, 
0.410055375, 0.422539538, 0.410779164, 0.457628614, 0.43332702, 
0.416031492, 0.385449931, 0.385559116, 0.456638369, 0.35700324, 
0.356313909, 0.428000987, 0.453316536, 0.468721167, 0.484492492, 
0.71133922, 0.384378145, 0.4598195, 0.479321219, 0.621036228, 
0.906049074, 0.500678212, 0.449753081, 0.558406891, 0.416631819, 
0.416657808, 0.377385168, 0.44650965, 0.427072537, 0.488751594, 
0.60657601, 0.560400225, 0.585830518, 0.425817237, 0.355278799, 
0.369649703, 0.209896438, 0.247075465, 0.235855363, 0.221755615, 
0.33047327, 0.40601357, 0.882391882, 0.547035853, 0.490244052, 
0.681514401, 0.254695241, 0.532014538, 0.317731086, 0.686983737, 
0.318569137, 0.412941472, 0.747218473, 0.491456148, 0.247013005, 
0.357590168, 0.366744683, 0.388101764, 0.560010709, 0.553912695, 
0.514254479, 0.637962019, 0.439514797, 0.518231241, 0.621825396, 
0.60808625, 0.519856265, 0.418285458, 0.797209677, 0.610643751, 
0.800145006, 0.695947222, 0.77037793, 0.723107131, 0.68680263, 
0.601738333, 0.351076727, 0.56076852, 0.698677466, 0.791374325, 
0.700144317, 0.767772946, 0.512633235, 0.554271018, 0.641965604, 
0.27547552, 0.728366986, 0.695140906, 0.656645469, 0.698677466, 
0.772628504, 0.22619292, 0.293919524, 0.36341721, 0.223714136, 
0.225174651, 0.242549001, 0.339565941, 0.349654473, 0.304779093, 
0.527638815, 0.807282781, 0.651922772, 0.575499597, 0.330912975, 
0.369287841, 0.448767932, 0.427866474, 0.350731808, 0.339157346, 
0.423145251, 0.433737212, 0.584266969, 0.669434408, 0.574057708, 
0.60651393, 0.356999618, 0.19465109, 0.447284959, 0.282473534, 
0.251865238, 0.49831024, 0.911487717, 0.757363095, 0.266577177, 
0.718247508), CTh = c(21.14809143, 20.46167879, 20.64893598, 
21.04530289, 20.32510752, 23.39119237, 0.471300128, 23.58126681, 
23.46994037, 23.624, 23.7528765, 22.70996891, 2.182182907, 23.89962439, 
0.48059366, 0.53276752, 23.50391614, 0.444647699, 0.799701978, 
0.851142776, 1.862630615, 22.5125215, 0.846569738, 24, 1.033225332, 
1.162990171, 0.616924156, 23.5964969, 3.101102259, 0.736601467, 
0.133734058, 0.082823932, 23.14546877, 1.589740954, 23.69739708, 
21.14628873, 22.87155186, 21.1751303, 20.06210696, 20.43805558, 
19.92768428, 19.87913114, 22.56225919, 19.45296265, 20.68734555, 
19.55736024, 21.21274243, 19.97004834, 0.59455942, 19.9058128, 
17.5177394, 17.27445458, 0.42211672, 22.71278515, 0.187528931, 
1.086895046, 1.624228644, 22.18426129, 0.173514186, 2.351566425, 
1.750740331, 2.7660905, 1.596337828, 19.73857433, 21.47333358, 
22.67911727, 22.65473537, 22.28943169, 21.75195704, 22.9452684, 
1.345266962, 20.98039379, 21.3138143, 21.37456775, 22.99755994, 
23.55959968, 23.77524494, 0.141658812, 1.730823926, 1.342053747, 
1.262339504, 1.340685217, 1.336531194, 1.16286759, 0.459159693, 
1.7307618, 1.777469985, 1.532612087, 1.140104543, 1.068574833, 
0.067861243, 2.644844993, 0.606791637, 0.89134981, 1.811195944, 
23.08626513, 0.071114302, 1.777469985, 1.296877407, 22.02793785, 
20.64329105, 21.196098, 22.71842443, 20.92718573, 22.25364904, 
21.27086113, 23.0188008, 1.738478694, 23.50344452, 0.662628194, 
0.485381794, 2.567074301, 2.930818844, 0.459018625, 23.61766479, 
22.76335766, 23.95562557, 22.47045433, 0.268279205, 1.871624048, 
0.554289283, 22.89387783, 1.337128041, 23.70281795, 0.182730588, 
22.49595319, 21.32281253, 0.601333476, 22.98575466, 20.55265406, 
0.580090548, 0.173828955, 0.515205971, 20.50591317), CTrad = c(317.2213715, 
306.9251819, 309.7340397, 315.6795434, 304.8766128, 350.8678855, 
367.0695019, 353.7190021, 352.0491056, 354.36, 356.2931475, 340.6495337, 
392.7327436, 358.4943659, 367.2089049, 367.9915128, 352.5587421, 
366.6697155, 371.9955297, 372.7671416, 387.9394592, 337.6878225, 
372.6985461, 360, 375.49838, 377.4448526, 369.2538623, 353.9474535, 
406.5165339, 371.049022, 362.0060109, 361.242359, 347.1820315, 
383.8461143, 355.4609562, 317.194331, 343.073278, 317.6269544, 
300.9316045, 306.5708338, 298.9152643, 298.1869671, 338.4338879, 
291.7944397, 310.3101833, 293.3604036, 318.1911364, 299.5507251, 
368.9183913, 298.5871919, 262.766091, 259.1168188, 366.3317508, 
340.6917773, 362.812934, 376.3034257, 384.3634297, 332.7639194, 
362.6027128, 395.2734964, 386.261105, 401.4913575, 383.9450674, 
296.0786149, 322.1000037, 340.186759, 339.8210305, 334.3414753, 
326.2793555, 344.1790259, 380.1790044, 314.7059069, 319.7072145, 
320.6185162, 344.963399, 353.3939951, 356.628674, 362.1248822, 
385.9623589, 380.1308062, 378.9350926, 380.1102782, 380.0479679, 
377.4430139, 366.8873954, 385.961427, 386.6620498, 382.9891813, 
377.1015681, 376.0286225, 361.0179186, 399.6726749, 369.1018746, 
373.3702472, 387.1679392, 346.2939769, 361.0667145, 386.6620498, 
379.4531611, 330.4190677, 309.6493658, 317.9414701, 340.7763665, 
313.907786, 333.8047356, 319.0629169, 345.282012, 386.0771804, 
352.5516678, 369.9394229, 367.2807269, 398.5061145, 403.9622827, 
366.8852794, 354.2649718, 341.4503649, 359.3343835, 337.0568149, 
364.0241881, 388.0743607, 368.3143392, 343.4081675, 380.0569206, 
355.5422693, 362.7409588, 337.4392979, 319.842188, 369.0200021, 
344.7863199, 308.2898109, 368.7013582, 362.6074343, 367.7280896, 
307.5886976)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -134L))


Does moving the colour= mapping from ggplot() to geom_point(), do the trick?

Omit the call to geom_dotplot(). I don't see the point of having this.

You can either move the "colour=group" aesthetic from the ggplot() call to geom_point() as mentioned in the comments, or omit the geom_dotplot() call as this is just changing the fill colour of the points in the legend to black and doesn't add anything to the plot.
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(process), y = CTrad, color=group)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(200,475,25)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=sample, size=-log(kuiper_q))) +
  # geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", position="dodge", 
  #              stackdir="centerwhole", binwidth=.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = iqr, geom = "pointrange", colour = "black")


